# Error creating method to modify UIButton

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch

I'm struggling to get a method to work on an iPhone app, other methods are working fine but this one acts up.

I want to pass two variables to a method that updates the title of a button. An INT for specifying the button, and a INT for referencing the text from a NSMutablearray. Here's the method:

```
void buttonLabelChange(int buttonNumber, int nameNumber){
    if (buttonNumber == 1) {
        [button1Outlet setTitle:[objectArray objectAtIndex:nameNumber] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    } else {
        [button2Outlet setTitle:[objectArray objectAtIndex:nameNumber] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    }
}
```

The error I get is: "Use of undeclared identifier 'button1Outlet'".
This EXACT code ([button1Outlet setTitle......) works like a charm in the "viewDidLoad" section..

My .h file contains:

```
void buttonLabelChange();
```

I've been bangning my head against the wall for the better part of the day, can't find anything useful (that I understand..) on google either. Suggestions?

---

THANKs FOR THE HELP!

---

Heres my new, working code:

.m

```
- (void)buttonLabelChange:(int)buttonNumber name:(int)nameNumber{
    if (buttonNumber == 1) {
        [button1Outlet setTitle:[objectArray objectAtIndex:nameNumber] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    } else {
        [button2Outlet setTitle:[objectArray objectAtIndex:nameNumber] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    }
}
```

.h

```
void buttonLabelChange();
```

And to call it:

```
[self buttonLabelChange:1 name:randomP1];
```

Comment: That's not a method, it's a function.

Comment: Why not a method (`- (void)buttonLabelChangeWithNumber:(int)buttonNumber nameNumber:(int)nameNumber`) ?

Comment: Noted. Trying it as a method. Thanks for the suggestion!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

your code is a c function, not an objective-c method. try replacing

```
void buttonLabelChange(int buttonNumber, int nameNumber)
```

with

```
- (void)buttonLabelChange:(int)buttonNumber name:(int)nameNumber
```

in both the .h and .m files.

Comment: That works! Or at least I'm a step closer.. Now during build I get "Undefined symbols for architecture i386" / "linker command failed with exit code 1".. The first call to this method is in the viewDidLoad.

Comment: Let me just add that the method does work! But still a bit annoying with the "undefined symobls.." message.. THANK YOU!

Comment: Ah, the undefined symbols error is a pain. A lot of the time it's because it can't find a framework reference, so make sure you've linked in all the frameworks you need in the project editor. Also, if you click the error you can get a detailed description of the problem.

Answer (score 1):

It's because you have put the code in a function, which is not part of your view object.  Just because the function is in the same implementation file as the view code, doesn't give it any special access to the view object.

Use a view method instead, or pass the view instance to the function (horrible as it requires exposing the outlets as well as the `objectArray`):

```
void buttonLabelChange(UIView *view, int buttonNumber, int nameNumber){
    if (buttonNumber == 1) {
        [view.button1Outlet setTitle:[view.objectArray objectAtIndex:nameNumber] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    } else {
        [view.button2Outlet setTitle:[view.objectArray objectAtIndex:nameNumber] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    }
}
```